# error "Se ha encontrado un error de división por cero" en SQL

Tags: sql

Hola a todos tengo una consulta que me realiza unas divisiones de saldos pero me esta regresando el siguiente error.

"Se ha encontrado un error de división por cero"

este es mi codigo donde divido

```
ISNULL(SUM(D.Foreign_Currency_Amount/E.Exchange_Rate + D.Foreign_Currency_Amount/E.Exchange_Rate / B.Tax_Rate),0) as 'Total Pago',
ISNULL(SUM(D.Foreign_Currency_Amount/E.Exchange_Rate),0) as 'Subtotal Pago',
ISNULL(SUM(D.Foreign_Currency_Amount/E.Exchange_Rate / B.Tax_Rate),0) as 'Total IVA Pago'
```

Comment: Hola. Está un poco... escueto el código de ejemplo. Cuál de todos los valores que tienes dividiendo será el que tienes en cero? Tampoco entiendo por qué pones etiquetas jquery si es una consulta. Es algo como grahql o algo así?

Comment: el campo que va en 0 es "B.Tax_Rate"

Comment: Pues eso, no dividas por cero. Valida el contenido de ese campo antes de ejecutar las consultas. Eso no va a dar NULL, lanza una excepción porque ya lo dice la biblia del programador: no dividirás por cero so pena de tener que arreglar bugs los viernes a las 8pm por toda la eternidad

Comment: @Alfabravo jijiji

Comment: ya tengo identificado el dato que me esta trayendo datos en 0, es "Tax_Amount" solo que no todos son 0 algunos registros si vienen con saldos y son los que me gustaria dividir.  estoy creando un case para esto pero aun asi me manda el mismo error                                                                                                       **CASE WHEN ISNULL(B.Tax_Amount,0) = 0 THEN 0
     WHEN ISNULL(B.Tax_Amount,0) > 0 THEN B.Tax_Amount/ISNULL(A.Amount/NULLIF(A.Foreign_Currency_Amount,0),0)/ E.Exchange_Rate
     END AS 'Total IVA Pago'**